# Sending an SMS to each group based on form selection(s)

Tags: python, django, sqlite, twilio

So I have an SMS app working perfectly with a Django form.  I have an sqlite table "Employees" and each employee has one relationship of either "dcare," "admin," or "recreation".  In my form, I used a radio button to select one of these relationships and the messages are sent to those employees...no problem there.  The issue is when I switched it from a radio button to a multiple choice widget.

So I am having trouble finding the appropriate language/syntax of "For each group selected, send the SMS to each person in that group."

Views.py below

[image]

```
def contact(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ContactForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                client = twilio.rest.TwilioRestClient('xxxx', 'xxxx')

                recipients = employees.objects.filter(group__contains=cd['togroup'])
                #check to see which group is selected
                if cd['togroup'] != "everyone":
                    for recipient in recipients:
                     client.messages.create(body=cd['message'],to=recipient.phone_number, from_='+xx')

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
            else:
                #if "everyone" is selected, change recips to all   
                recipients = employees.objects.all()
                for recipient in recipients:
                    client.messages.create(body=cd['message'], to=recipient.phone_number, from_='+xxxx')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
        else:
            form = ContactForm()
        return render(request, 'contact_form.html', {'form':
form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `cd['togroup']` returns an array of selected choices e.g. `['dcare', 'recreation']`. From your flow (For each group selected, send the SMS to each person in that group.), I would do:

```
for to_group in cd['togroup']:
    recipients = employees.objects.filter(group=to_group)
    for recipient in recipients:
       client.messages.create(body=cd['message'],to=recipient.phone_number, from_='+xx')
```